# Replace only last path part in URL not parametres

Tags: javascript, url, href, pushstate

I can change the last part (in the URL: `child`) of the URL, but if the URL's parameters exist, these parameters are deleted by this change (`?para=1&para=2`).

Is there a way to **not** delete the parameters?

Sample:

```
https://example.com/sub/child?para=1&para=2
```

JS:

```
const str = window.location.href;
const lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
const path = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
const new_path = path + "/new_child";
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", new_path);
window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title", new_path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before replacing the last part you can save the parameters like this

```js
var str = "https://example.com/sub/child?para=1&para=2";
var params = str.split('?')[1]
const lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
const path = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
const new_path = path + "/new_child?"+params;
console.log(new_path)
```

Alternatively you can create a function to do this using regex

```js
var str = "https://example.com/sub/child?para=1&para=2";
const new_path = replaceUrlPart(str, "child", "new_child")
console.log(new_path)

function replaceUrlPart(url, partToRemove, partToAdd){
 return url.replace(partToRemove,partToAdd);
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I add `window.location.href` code instead of URL(str):  `Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const lastIndex`

Comment: You are redeclaring `lastIndex` somewhere can i see the updated code?

Comment: `var str = window.location.href;
var params = str.split('?')[1]
var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
var path = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
var new_path = path + "/new_child?"+params;
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", new_path);
window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title", new_path);
`

Comment: Your code looks fine. I ran it on my machine. Still getting that error?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I fixed my mistake and it worked. Thank you for your help.